# MVC model binding naming convention for child objects?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, naming-conventions, model-binding

I'm having trouble with default model binding naming convention when there is a child property. For example:

I have a ViewModel which looks something like this:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public User BusinessObject { get; set; }
}
```

My User class has a property called "NetworkLogin"

My View has something like this:
                
                    <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.BusinessObject.NetworkLogin)%>
                
                
                    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BusinessObject.NetworkLogin)%>
                    Auto-Fill

And my controller, what I'd like to do, is

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult UserIndex(string networkLogin) { }
```

The problem:
The input parameter "networkLogin" is always null. This makes sense, because the actual parameter on the html element is name="BusinessObject.NetworkLogin" and id="BusinessObject_NetworkLogin". However, I don't know what parameter name I should use in my action method. I've tried "businessObject_NetworkLogin" and it doesn't work either.

However, I have this workaround that does work, but I don't like it. I add this to my ViewModel:

```
    public string NetworkLogin
    {
        get
        {
            if (BusinessObject == null)
                BusinessObject = new User(); 
            return BusinessObject.NetworkLogin;
        } 
        set
        {
            if (BusinessObject == null)
                BusinessObject = new User();
            BusinessObject.NetworkLogin = value;
        }
    }
```

And my View page now says this instead.
                    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NetworkLogin)%>

Can someone tell me what the proper naming convention is for default model binding so that I don't have to employ the above workaround?

Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

Indicate the prefix so that the model binder knows that the `BusinessObject.NetworkLogin` query string parameter actually refers to `networkLogin` which is what you use as action argument

```
public ActionResult UserIndex(
    [Bind(Prefix = "BusinessObject")] string networkLogin
) 
{ 
    ...
}
```

or reuse your view model:

```
public ActionResult UserIndex(UserViewModel model) 
{ 
    // TODO: use model.BusinessObject.NetworkLogin
    // which is gonna be correctly bound here
    ...
}
```

As far as your workaround is concerned, once you put one of my two suggestions into action your view model property should really look like this:

```
public string NetworkLogin { get; set; }
```

Comment: this looks like it should work, but I've decided to use some ajax calls instead, so I don't readily have my project ready to try out the above.

Comment: +1 for Darin for what looks like a great answer.  Raymond, the least you could have done would have been to try this on an old revision.