# mvc begin form cant make routing override work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

simnilar to the answer of this question
[Html.BeginForm with html attributes asp.net mvc4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972558/html-beginform-with-html-attributes-asp-net-mvc4)

I have a viewmodel for a view that contains collections that are used to populate drop downs and lists. so i dont watn to return them, i just want to return the model object. Well actually i just want to return 4 fields in that model - but that's the next problem.
I've dodged that rpeviously by doing this appraoch but im having no luck unless i submit the entire viewmodel which on this form is ridiculous as 95% of info is discarded.

Anyway the problem i get here is that i cannot get the game event that is returned in the create post to be anything other than null. The gameEvent parameter on create is NULL.

Also kinda suprised i haven't been able to find a ton of info on this.

The controller:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ...

        var createEventViewModel = new CreateEventViewModel()
        {
            Places = places,
            Characters = characters,
            Event = new GameEvent()
        };

        return this.View(createEventViewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Name,Description,EventType,Duration")] GameEvent gameEvent)
    {
        ...
    }
```

The View:

```
  @model Sisyphus.Web.Models.CreateEventViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create Event";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create Event</h2>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <section id="createEvent">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Event",
                new
                {
                    GameEvent = Model.Event
                }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Event.Name, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Event.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Event.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Event.Description, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Event.Description, 10, 30, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Event.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Event.Duration, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Event.Duration, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Event.Duration, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Event.EventType, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.Event.EventType)
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Create Event" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Model:

```
public class GameEvent
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int Duration { get; set; }

    public EventType EventType { get; set; }
}
```

The viewmodel: (edited down have removed members that are irrelevant

```
public class CreateEventViewModel
{
    public GameEvent Event { get; set; }
}
```

Edit:
Ok i just tried this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Event",
                new RouteValueDictionary()
                {
                    {"GameEvent", Model.Event}
                }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
```

Game event is now not null (All values in it are) - so not really any closer

Comment: How are you creating your inputs? @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GameEvent.Name) would generate `<input name="GameEvent.Name"...` but this would not be bound in the action method because its expecting just `Name` (your parameter is `GameEvent` not `CreateEventViewModel`)

Comment: ill edit to include that code then ... 1 sec

Comment: cool that's interesting and might solve a different problem (and let me do what i really want to do) ... how would i name the parameter so it could automagically bind to the input "GameEvent.Name" as above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inputs for postback are based on `class CreateEventViewModel`, for example

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Event.Name, ...
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Event.Description, ...
```

which would generate the following html

```
<input id="Event_Name" name="Event.Name" value=....
```

However the parameter of your post action method is typeof `GameEvent`, not `CreateEventViewModel`.  If you inspect the `Response.Form.Keys` you will see `Event.Name`, `Event.Description` etc, but `class GameEvent` has properties `Name`, `Description` etc so the values cant be matched up by the `ModelBinder`

You need to change your post method to

```
public ActionResult Create(CreateEventViewModel model)
{
   GameEvent event = model.GameEvent;
  // do whatever with GameEvent
```

You should also remove `new {GameEvent = Model.Event} from the`Html.BeginForm` method

Note I excluded the BindAttibute because I don't think its necessary in this case - you appear to want all the properties of GameEvent, and unless you create inputs for properties of  `Places` and `Characters`, they will be null anyway, and since you are not accessing the other properties there is no mass assignment vulnerability.

Other alternative are to create the inputs manually so that the properties are correctly mapped, either direct html

```
<input name="Name" value=@Model.Event.Name />
<input name="Description" value=@Model.Event.Desciption />
```

or using helpers

```
var Description = Model.Event.Description;
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Description)
```

Comment: I said this is what i did not want to do. I Want to return the model part of the viewmodel - NOT the viewmodel. I actually just want to return 4 fields from the model rather than the whole thing (which is edited down here - but as i said above that is my next problem) There is an override that seems to do what i want - i am asking how to make that work. There are many situations where you do not want to return the entire viewmodel because you only want a small portion of its data. However you gave me an idea

Comment: Because you are only posting back the properties of `Event`, that's all that you will get (everything else is null). But an alternative is to manually create the input names for binding, for example `var Name = Model.Event.Name; @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Name,..` to generate `<input name="Name" ...`

Comment: This statement _unless i submit the entire viewmodel which on this form is ridiculous as 95% of info is discarded._ is not strictly true. Only inputs and selects are posted back. If your using `@Html.DisplayFor()` or manually creating display elemments for the other properties, they will not be posted back

Comment: that var name trick didn't work - no textbox was displayed. other info is very useful though thanks. Would still like to know ow to bind parts of the viewmodel to arbitrarily named parameters though. I much prefer to explicitly hook stuff up.

Comment: I foudn this  I foudn this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270115/mvc-model-binding-naming-convention-for-child-objects but couldn't get that working either ... but couldnt get it working in mvc5. still playing with that though

Comment: Just tried the `var Name=` bit and it works for me. Of course you can always create the inputs manually `<input name="Name" value=@Model.Event.Name />`

Comment: 'Response.Form' seems to be 'HttpContext.Request.Form' as Response has no form property. An you add a code snippet fro the var name thing please. I couldn't get that working still. It will be a great workaround if i cant get that bind prefix working.

Comment: Yes your right, that should have been Request, not Response :). I'll update answer with the alternatives.